# Putting an XML query inside a drop down list control

Tags: apache-flex

I have this project for school where i have to populate a drop down list control from an xml file.
I mange to do that for a label/text input control, but i can't seem to do that on a drop down.
I get this error any time i tell him to "additem" with an xml query (not getting it with simple text):
"#1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference"

This is the function that getting the xml file:

```
private function myFunc(event:ResultEvent):void
{
   myXml=event.result as XML;
}
```

This is the function that launch after the control got build:

```
protected function ActivityDropDown_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{

    droplistdb=new ArrayList();
    ActivityDropDown.dataProvider=droplistdb;
    droplistdb.addItem({label:myXml.Activity.(attribute("publish")=="true").ActivityName});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an Activity element with attribute publish that is true in your XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple tweaks that should make debugging this a bit easier.

First don't create a new ArrayList just for the DropDown's dataprovider. Just set the XMLList of Actitivies as the dataProvider and use a labelFunction to grab the ActivityName out of the XML.

Here's your debug labelFunction:

```
//set a breakpoint on each line
function(obj:XML):String{
  var activityName:XML = obj.ActivityName;
  return activityName.toString();
}
```

If you don't get to the label function then this E4X query is wrong -> myXml.Activity.(attribute("publish")=="true"). You'll want to break that down piece by piece. Try to get a proper XMLList out of myXml.Activity nodes?

```
trace(myXml.Activity.length());//should show the number of Activity nodes
```

Try that out and let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, first of all the e4x query is correct i know that because i set it to a label and it gave me what i wanted. Second, i found out what's the problem is:part of it was a non updated flash player. The other part is that the creation complete function doesn't get an initialized "myXml" variable. meaning it gets an empty variable. If i test the query in the first function "myfunc" it's works great.

Comment: okay cool. debugging XML can be a bit of a pain at times since its not structured like a traditional object (the price to pay for the sweet querying syntax).

Comment: So after i found what seem to be the problem, i mixed the two function and now its working. Thanks for the try here is what worked for me:private function myFunc(event:ResultEvent):void
   {
    myXml=event.result as XML;
    droplistdb=new ArrayList();
    ActivityDropDown.dataProvider=droplistdb;
    droplistdb.addItem({label:myXml.Activity.(attribute("publish")=="true").ActivityName});
   }